# Root certificate installation and Server Certificate validation in Embedded Device

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, openssl

I have gone through articles on google for adding a root certificate on my Embedded Device to validate Server Certificate During Handshake. but still, I am not clear  about a few topics

1) do we need to install these certificates with OpenSSL command or need to work on OpenSSL code 
2) does OpenSSL code will take care of validating Server Certificate during the handshake or any other model we need to follow?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as "unclear what you are asking" because it lacks the minimum information required to provide answer. In particular, we don't know what platform for embedded device we are talking about, operating system and the application that will use TLS. It seems to me that the OP is extremely confused on the topic and should learn more about how *applications* establish trust stores before asking the question. Perhaps, learning more will help the OP leveraging the rubber-duck effect. Good luck.

Comment: There is no generic embedded device and there is no generic way to add root certificates independent of the kind of device and the kind of application which uses these certificates. There is also not a single SSL library, i.e. something else might be used instead of OpenSSL. In other words: there is not enough detail in your question to help you.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ my intention is to verify Server Certificates in my Linux Machin which doesn't have any Browser

Comment: You may probably want to describe your problem better on Stackoverflow. We need to know what kind of application do you run. I can tell, from a design point of view, that embedded devices running any OS should **be cleared** their trust store and then added the very single root certificate they must trust